# why my .gltf object disappears when hovering over browser

Tags: three.js, gltf

I'm having issues with trying to implement movement of my object in `three.js`. It's suppose to respond to cursor movement and rotate a bit, however when I put cursor on the window the object disappears.

I created this app using `three.js` that loads an `.gltf` object this way.

```js
var loaded_gltf
const loader = new GLTFLoader();
loader.load('/keyboard.gltf', function(gltf) {
  loaded_gltf = gltf.scene
  scene.add( loaded_gltf );
})
```

I've setup the scene etc. and everything worked fine. But after adding this code:

```js
document.addEventListener('mousemove', onDocumentMouseMove)

let mouseX = 0 
let mouseY = 0 
let targetX = 0 
let targetY = 0 

const windowHalfX = window.innerWidth / 2
const windowHalfY = window.innerHeight / 2

function onDocumentMouseMove(event) {
  mouseX = (event.clientX - windowHalfX)
  mouseY = (event.clientXY - windowHalfY)
}

const clock = new THREE.Clock()

const loop = () => {
  targetX = mouseX * .001 
  targetY = mouseY * .001 
  const elapsedTime = clock.getElapsedTime()
  if(loaded_gltf) loaded_gltf.rotation.y -= .05 * (targetX - loaded_gltf.rotation.y)
  if(loaded_gltf) loaded_gltf.rotation.x -= .05 * (targetY - loaded_gltf.rotation.x)
  if(loaded_gltf) loaded_gltf.rotation.z -= .05 * (targetY - loaded_gltf.rotation.x)
  // controls.update()
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
  window.requestAnimationFrame(loop)
}
loop()
```

I started having issues with the object disappearing. I commented out every line of code that had something to do with `OrbitControls` because I thought it might be intervening but that doesn't seem to change anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a typo on your `onDocumentMouseMove` function. The property `event.clientXY` doesn't exist, so this creates an `undefined` value that breaks your rotations. You probably want `event.clientY` instead.

You're also making another mistake in your loop by using `rotation.x` twice, it looks like you should be using `rotation.z` the second time.

Comment: thanks for the answer! i fixed my code and now my object doesn't disappear but instead it just rotates very fast. i tried changing the numbers but it just starts slow and goes really fast after a couple of seconds.

Comment: That sounds like a different problem altogether. You could just use smaller values when adding your rotations, but you should start a new question outlining the problem and desired behavior. If this answer helped solve your initial problem, feel free to +1 or accept it as answered. Thanks!